# How to get Percentages with reference to one number in my table which is 100 % in R, with tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse, percentage

I am trying to get `Percentages`, in R, with tidyverse:

- based on the first row `NSTEMI` which regardless of its counts (compared to the following categories) `is always 100 %`.
- Yet I want my percentages `'Seen by Cardiologist', 'Admitted to Cardiac Unit or Ward', 'Eligible for Angiography'` to be calculated with reference to `NSTEMI`. In lay language will sound like - `out of NSTEMI how much percentage have been seen by the cardiologist, admitted to cardiac unit and are eligible for angiography`;
- Yet, the last two rows `'Underwent Angiography' and 'Underwent Angiography Before Discharge'` and `their Percentages` to be calculated with reference to the `'Eligible for Angiography'` which `is my fourth row`. It is like from `'Eligible for Angiography' how many 'Underwent Angiography' and 'Underwent angiography before discharge'`

This is my sample of data :

```
structure(list(Category = c("NSTEMI", "Seen by cardiologist", 
"Admitted to cardiac unit or Ward", "Eligible for angiography", 
"Underwent angiography", "Underwent angiography before discharge"
), Counts = c(196L, 196L, 158L, 174L, 174L, 173L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

An example of the table I want looks as bellow picture:

[image]

As observed, the table I want is done based on my principles designed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This special task isn't a real show case for `tidyverse`. But you could use:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,2))) %>% 
  mutate(Frequency  = Counts/first(Counts),
         Percentage = paste0(round(Frequency * 100, 2), " %")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Category                               Counts Frequency Percentage
  <chr>                                   <int>     <dbl> <chr>     
1 NSTEMI                                    196     1     100 %     
2 Seen by cardiologist                      196     1     100 %     
3 Admitted to cardiac unit or Ward          158     0.806 80.61 %   
4 Eligible for angiography                  174     0.888 88.78 %   
5 Underwent angiography                     174     1     100 %     
6 Underwent angiography before discharge    173     0.994 99.43 %
```

This solution is based on the position of your `Category`s, if necessary you could use a string comparison.

I created a grouping variable: the first four rows of your data belong to group 1, the last two into group 2. `c(rep(1,4), rep(2,2))` creates that grouping: `1 1 1 1 2 2`, 1 is repeated four times, 2 twice. The `first`-function takes the first element of a group. Thanks to the grouping the first element of group 1 is taken from row `NSTEMI`, the first element of group 2 from row `Underwent angiography`.

Comment: thank you it worked. One aspect, what is c(rep(1,4), rep(2,2,_ and first function does?

Comment: I created a grouping variable: the first four rows of your data belong to group 1, the last two into group 2. `c(rep(1,4), rep(2,2))` creates that grouping: `1 1 1 1 2 2`, 1 is repeated four times, 2 twice. The `first`-function takes the first element of a group. Thanks to the grouping the first element of group 1 is taken from row `NSTEMI`, the first element of group 2 from row `Underwent angiography`.

Comment: This solution works for *this* special dataset. If the order of your rows changes or there are additional rows, this won't work anymore. In this case we need to adjust the code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It would be nice to be part of the post so that people can see clearly!

Comment: Good point. Copy and pasted it into the answer.